# using berkshelf programmatically

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook, berkshelf

i am managing my cookbooks with [berkshelf](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf).
i would like to play a little bit with the cookbook dependency graph. for instance:

- given a cookbook, get its dependencies (the same as the resolver does it)
- given a cookbook, get depended cookbooks (same as `berks contingent`)

i tried

```
require 'berkshelf'
Berkshelf::Lockfile.new(file_path: './Berksfile.lock')
```

but it did not work.

how can berkshelf be invoked programmatically under ruby and achieve the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Berksfile, It might be helpful for you.

```
require 'berkshelf'

# initializing berksfile
s = Berkshelf::Berksfile.from_file('./find_versions/Berksfile')

#install dependencies to create Berksfile.lock 
s.install()

# parse lockfile
s.lockfile().parse()

# find dependencies
puts s.find('cookbook_name').locked_version
```

Comment: the `find()` returns nil for cookbook dependencies although there is a lock file

Comment: According to this doc, find will return nil if dependency not found in berksfile.lock. https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/berkshelf/Berkshelf/Berksfile#find-instance_method

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported, or anything even in the same area code as supported. We have no public Ruby APIs for this data, sorry. You can look at the Solve gem, but it's not really used outside of our own use cases.

Comment: thank you for the reply. i just cannot believe what i am hearing -- do i need to develop a new code for parsing the berksfile lock to analyze the dependency tree? ohhh i wish there was a way to reuse berkshelf code...

Comment: This is rapidly becoming out of scope for SO comments, but it depends entirely on what you are trying to accomplish.